# How to get ajax post data in views.py?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I try to submit a form using ajax, the issue is the request.POST is always empty, the server reply successfully to the request but no data are coming.

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#step1").click(function(e) {
       
     console.log($('#form-one').serialize())
     var csrftoken = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
      e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({ 
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
            },
              data: $('#form-one').serialize(), 
              type: 'POST', 
              url: '/commande/test', 
              success: function(response) { 
                  console.log("success !")
              }
          });
          return false;
      });
  });
```

views.py

```
def test(request):
    
    nadjib = modelformset_factory(Commande_Designation, form=Commande_D_Form, extra=1, can_delete=True)
    formset = nadjib(queryset=Commande.objects.none())
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:
            print('post test 1')
            
            
            print(request.POST)// empty !!
            .............
```

Comment: .data should be an object - try data: {$('#form-one').serialize()}

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the status of your form, I'd say you're safer making the data element in .ajax an object. You can revert to sending the form as individual parameters once you have it working.

And I recommend an error handler - without it errors are silent and the ajax seems not to have worked at all:

Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
        },
          data: { mydata : $('#form-one').serialize()}, 
          type: 'POST', 
          url: '/commande/test', 
          success: function(response) { 
              console.log("success !")
          },
          error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
         },

      });
```

Then you should see a parameter in $_POST called "mydata".